# How to check that element of validate is present in list of tuples in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need your guidance in how to check that item in tuple(validate) is present in list of tuples(db), and if that item is present in 'db' then I want to print other items of that tuple. I tried some sort of techniques but none of them works. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 validate = ('1', 'green', '14:54:54:65:66:89', '456456', '2') 

db = [('456456', 'rajat', 'rajat@gmail.com', '8764285479'), ('123456',
 'rahul', 'rahul@gmail.com', '32478524785')]
```

For example:-
Item in validate that is on index[3], how will I able to know that this item is present in which tuple of db?

what I tried --

```
val1 = []
val = validate[3]
val1.append(val)
print(val1)


if (any(val1 in i for i in db)) :
    print('item exists')
else:
    print('item does not exists')
```

Comment: @rajatmaan simply create 2 loops over 2 lists and compare items

Comment: @rajatmaan just use `val` instead of `val1`. `val1` is a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by iterating over the two elements like so:

```
 for item in validate:
    for item2 in db:
        if item in item2:
              print(item2, item)
```

note that the result prints the tuple in the db and the item which appears in it, like you asked.

Comment: Sir, it works but i want to store item2 in an variable so that I can send it through socket.

Comment: You might want to look at `filter` @rajatmaan.

Comment: @rajatmaan cool do that...